# Paperclip photo upload via RestKit or any HTTP request

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, mongoid, paperclip, restkit

I'm using mongoid-paperclip to upload images on amazon s3, and it is working fine on the web using multipart/form-data.

But when I try to upload images using HTTP PUT request using CURL or RestKit updating the profile works and returns `{ status: ok }` but the file doesn't get uploaded.

### User Class

```
has_mongoid_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => {
      :original => ['1000x1000>', :png],
      :small    => ['64x64#',     :png],
      :medium   => ['250x250',    :png],
      :large    => ['500x500>',   :png]
    },
    :convert_options => { :all => '-background white -flatten +matte' }
```

**So now I don't know where the problem is, is it from RestKit or from paperclip?**

Answer (score 0):

If anyone got that same problem as you need to call

```
current_user.avatar = params[:avatar]
```

Explanation

`current_user` is user currently logged in, any user will work too

`avatar` is my paperclip name

`params[:avatar]` is the file your are trying to upload